# AlaSQL saved database location

Tags: alasql

Where can I find the locations that are made from alasql? For example

```
alasql('CREATE TABLE one (two INT)');
```

Where is table one will be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table `one` will be saved in the global variable `alasql.tables.one`.

The data you put into the table `one` will be located in the global variable `alasql.tables.one.data`.